# How to add divider view via code

Tags: android

Container is a LinearLayout,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

In code, I am trying to add views as:

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// add alpha view to container view
View alphaView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_info_alpha, null, false);
container.addView(alphaView);

// add divider view to container view
container.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_divider, null, false));

// add beta view to container view
View betaView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_info_beta, null, false);
container.addView(betaView);

// add divider view to container view
container.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_divider, null, false));
```

item_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:background="#F2F2F4" />
```

Divider is not visible when adding via code.

How to make this divider visible when adding views to linear layout ?

Why when we add **View** via xml, it is not adding up in the LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that:

```
container.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_divider, null));
```

Or try this code:

```
        View view = new View(YOUR_CONTEXT); //getContext() for example
        int hight = 8;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, hight);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F2F2F4"));
        container.addView(view);
```

Comment: container.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_divider, null)); will not work

Comment: @purplebee it will, see the  docs : `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)`

Comment: @purplebee is right: `container.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_divider, null))` wont work because `root` is `null`. So it wont correctly assign LayoutParams. You have to provide root view in order to assign LayoutParams correctly

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `false` in `inflater.inflate(..)` with `true` and do not explicitly call `addView(..)` on `LinearLayout`.

The purpose of a `LayoutInflater` is to not have to set `LayoutParams` manually.

If you inflate a `View` with `attachToRoot=false`, the `LayoutParams` of root are used to create the new `View` and then discarded.

If `attachToRoot=true`, the `LayoutParams` are kept and also the new `View` is attached to the rootView, in your case `LinearLayout`.

Comment: You tried to answer "Why" part, but I didnt get it.

Comment: Okay, every View has a set of variables called LayoutParams that decide where to put the view on screen, how big it is, etc. if you simply call addView(), the view is added but has no LayoutParams, thus it does not know how to display itself

Comment: to fix that, either explicitly call setLayoutParams() OR use LayoutInflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, true) <= the true stands for "attach the new inflated view to the parent ViewGroup and also use LayoutParams please so my parent knows how i want to look on the screen."